# Best practice for Video Streaming to Azure Blob Storage Net.Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, video-streaming, azure-blob-storage, hololens

I would like to stream video TO Azure blob storage (I think I should use Append Blob which is optimized for data streaming). I'm going to use NET.Core (because actually the video is coming from Hololens). What are the best practicies to achive that? I try to dig a little bit on internet, but I found few related topics. Thanks.

Comment: Please use Block Blobs instead of Append Blobs.

Comment: @GauravMantri Append blob is the operation not the type of blob

Answer (score 1):

If you have plans to stream to possible multiple users consider to use Azure Media Services and also CDN to save cost with network out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-dotnet-quickstart

Comment: Thanks @ThiagoCustodio I'll give a look pretty soon to the tutorial. The main idea is to persist the video on blob storage for further use in the future. Just a quick question, is it possible to use Azure Media Service to stream video from a device into blob storage?

Comment: The output from Media Services is a blob into a container.